# Laravel 5: Type-hinting a FormRequest class inside a controller that extends from BaseController

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection, laravel-5, ioc-container

I have a `BaseController` that provides the foundation for most HTTP methods for my API server, e.g. the `store` method:

*BaseController.php*

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $result = $this->repo->create($request);

    return response()->json($result, 200);
}
```

I then extend on this `BaseController` in a more specific controller, such as the `UserController`, like so:

*UserController.php*

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

}
```

This works great. However, I now want to extend `UserController` to inject Laravel 5's new `FormRequest` class, which takes care of things like validation and authentication for the `User` resource. I would like to do this like so, by overwriting the store method and using Laravel's type hint dependency injection for its Form Request class.

*UserController.php*

```
public function store(UserFormRequest $request)
{
    return parent::store($request);
}
```

Where the `UserFormRequest` extends from `Request`, which itself extends from `FormRequest`:

*UserFormRequest.php*

```
class UserFormRequest extends Request {

    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'  => 'required',
            'email' => 'required'
        ];
    }

}
```

The problem is that the `BaseController` requires a `Illuminate\Http\Request` object whereas I pass a `UserFormRequest` object. Therefore I get this error:

```
in UserController.php line 6
at HandleExceptions->handleError('2048', 'Declaration of Bloomon\Bloomapi3\Repositories\User\UserController::store() should be compatible with Bloomon\Bloomapi3\Http\Controllers\BaseController::store(Illuminate\Http\Request $request)', '/home/tom/projects/bloomon/bloomapi3/app/Repositories/User/UserController.php', '6', array('file' => '/home/tom/projects/bloomon/bloomapi3/app/Repositories/User/UserController.php')) in UserController.php line 6
```

So, how can I type hint inject the UserFormRequest while still adhering to the BaseController's Request requirement? I cannot force the BaseController to require a UserFormRequest, because it should work for any resource.

I could use an interface like `RepositoryFormRequest` in both the `BaseController` and the `UserController`, but then the problem is that Laravel no longer injects the `UserFormController` through its type hinting dependency injection.

Comment: You can move the methods from your BaseController to a Trait and then use it on the other controllers.

Comment: Are you using Laravel's RESTful Resource Controllers? And so what to stick to the preset names like `store`?

Comment: @Chris yes I am. I'm not sure I follow your question, could you please rephrase?

Comment: Ugh, this is a huge design flaw in method type-hinting... Makes the whole thing seem almost useless.

Answer (score 10):

In contrast to many 'real' object oriented languages, this kind of type hinting design in overridden methods is just not possible in PHP, see:

```
class X {}
class Y extends X {}

class A {
    function a(X $x) {}
}

class B extends A {
    function a(Y $y) {} // error! Methods with the same name must be compatible with the parent method, this includes the typehints
}
```

This produces the same kind of error as your code. I would just not put a `store()` method in your `BaseController`. If you feel that you are repeating code, consider introducing for example a service class or maybe a trait.

**Using a service class**

Below a solution that makes use of an extra service class. This might be overkill for your situation. But if you add more functionality to the `StoringService`s `store()` method (like validation), it could be useful. You can also add more methods to the `StoringService` like `destroy()`, `update()`, `create()`, but then you probably want to name the service differently.

```
class StoringService {

    private $repo;

    public function __construct(Repository $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $result = $this->repo->create($request);

        return response()->json($result, 200);
    }
}

class UserController {

    // ... other code (including member variable $repo)

    public function store(UserRequest $request)
    {
        $service = new StoringService($this->repo); // Or put this in your BaseController's constructor and make $service a member variable
        return $service->store($request);
    }

}
```

**Using a trait**

You can also use a trait, but you have to rename the trait's `store()` method then:

```
trait StoringTrait {

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $result = $this->repo->create($request);

        return response()->json($result, 200);
    }
}

class UserController {

    use {
        StoringTrait::store as baseStore;
    }

    // ... other code (including member variable $repo)

    public function store(UserRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->baseStore($request);
    }

}
```

The advantage of this solution is that if you do not have to add extra functionality to the `store()` method, you can just `use` the trait without renaming and you do not have to write an extra `store()` method.

**Using inheritance**

In my opinion, inheritance is not so suitable for the kind of code reuse that you need here, at least not in PHP. But if you want to only use inheritance for this code reuse problem, give the `store()` method in your `BaseController` another name, make sure that all classes have their own `store()` method and call the method in the `BaseController`. Something like this:

*BaseController.php*

```
/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @return Response
 */
protected function createResource(Request $request)
{
    $result = $this->repo->create($request);

    return response()->json($result, 200);
}
```

*UserController.php*

```
public function store(UserFormRequest $request)
{
    return $this->createResource($request);
}
```

Comment: Don't you think it's strange to create a `store` and a `createResource` method, that have an identical purpose, but widely different names? It seems more like a workaround than a solution?

Comment: Yeah, it is not a good solution. As I said, inheritance in PHP is not the best way to solve this repeating code problem. This work around however is the most similar to what you tried. But there are better solutions for sure.

Comment: @Tom, I added another solution that uses an extra service class.

Comment: in your service example, it doesn't matter that you pass a `UserRequest` object to the `StorageService`'s method that expects a `Request` object, rather than a `UserRequest` object? The same problem applies to the trait solution.

Comment: Since `UserRequest` extends `Request`, each instance of `UserRequest` is also an instance of `Request`, so the instance will match the typehint, this should not be a problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can move your logic from BaseController to trait, service, facade.

You can not override existing function and force it to use different type of argument, it would break stuff. For example, if you later would write this:

```
function foo(BaseController $baseController, Request $request) {
    $baseController->store($request);
}
```

It would break with your `UserController` and `OtherRequest` because `UserController` expects `UserController`, not `OtherRequest` (which extends `Request` and is valid argument from `foo()` perspective).

Comment: If I move the method from the BaseController to a trait, how does that resolve the issue where the BaseController (or the new trait)'s `store` method expects a `Request` object rather than a `FormRequest` as passed by the `UserController`'s store method?

Comment: If you use trait with the same method you will have to change it's name in controller `use ControllerTrait { ControllerTrait::store as traitStore; }`. Personally I would go with something like: `$this->helper->store($request)`. You can even create this in your `BaseController` if every child will be using it.

Answer (score 4):

As others have mentioned, you cannot do what you want to do for a host of reasons. As mentioned, you can solve this problem with traits or similar. I am presenting an alternative approach.

At a guess, it sounds like you are trying to follow the naming convention put forth by Laravel's `RESTful Resource Controllers`, which is kind of forcing you to use a particular method on a controller, in this case, `store`.

Looking at the source of `ResourceRegistrar.php` we can see that in the `getResourceMethods` method, Laravel does either a diff or intersect with the options array you pass in and against the default values. However, the those defaults are protected, and include `store`.

What this means is that you can't pass anything to `Route::resource` to force some override of the route names. So let's rule that out.

A simpler approach would be to simply set up a different method just for this route. This can be achieved by doing:

```
Route::post('user/save', 'UserController@save');
Route::resource('users', 'UserController');
```

Note: As per the documentation, the custom routes must come prior to the Route::resource call.

Comment: This would require me to completely rewrite the save function, right? I cannot re-use the boilerplate save logic, resulting in repeating code

Comment: Laravel offers ease of use, which comes at the expense of flexibility. If you are looking for decoupled mostly independent components, look into symfony2.

Answer (score 2):

The declaration of `UserController::store()` should be compatible with `BaseController::store()`, which means (among other things) that the given parameters for both the `BaseController` as well as `UserController` should be exactly the same.

You actually cán force the BaseController to require a UserFormRequest, it's not the prettiest solution, but it works.

By overwriting there is no way you can replace `Request` with `UserFormRequest`, so why not use both? Giving both methods an optional parameter for injecting the `UserFormRequest` object. Which would result in:

*BaseController.php*

```
class BaseController {

  public function store(Request $request, UserFormRequest $userFormRequest = null)
  {
      $result = $this->repo->create($request);
      return response()->json($result, 200);
  }

}
```

*UserController.php*

```
class UserController extends BaseController {

    public function __construct(UserRepository $repo)
    {
        $this->repo = $repo;
    }

    public function store(UserFormRequest $request, UserFormRequest $userFormRequest = null)
    {
        return parent::store($request);
    }

}
```

This way you can ignore the parameter when using `BaseController::store()` and inject it when using `UserController::store()`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest and cleanest way I found to circumvent that problem was to prefix the parent methods with an underscore. For example:

BaseController:

- `_store(Request $request) { ... }`
- `_update(Request $request) { ... }`

UserController:

- `store(UserFormRequest $request) { return parent::_store($request); }`
- `update(UserFormRequest $request) { return parent::_update($request); }`

I feel like creating service providers is an overkill. What we're trying to circumvent here is not the Liskov substitution principle, but simply the lack of proper PHP reflection. Type-hinting methods is, in itself, a hack after all.

This will force you to manually implement a `store` and `update` in every child controller. I don't know if that's bothersome for your design, but in mine, I use custom requests for each controller, so I had to do it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

And If I use DI to send UserFormRequest into __construct of UserController, All functions of BaseController will be validated with UserFormRequest.

```
class UserController extends BaseController
{
    protected $service;

    public function __construct(IUserService $service, UserFormRequest  $validation)
    {

        parent::__construct($service, $validation);
    }
}
```